# How to get all departments with Employee number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an EmployeeDepartmetn juction table like this. I have all the departments in Depeartment table and employees in Employee table..[image]

I want to get departments for an particular employee along with the all the departments available in depeartment table.

It should be like Select DepartmentId, DepartmentName, EmployeeID from Query.

Main criteria here is, Need to display NULL if the employee dont have that department. I am confused here...please help.

Please give Linq Query

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select DeptId,
       max(case when EmployeeId = 1 then EmployeeId end) as EmployeeId
from EmployeeDepartment ed
group by DeptId;
```

EDIT:

If you have a `departments` table as well:

```
select d.deptid, d.name, ed.employeeid
from Departments d left join
     EmployeeDepartment ed
     on d.deptid = ed.deptid and
        ed.employeeid = 1;
```

Comment: Can you give me the same in linq...I am trying but I am unable to give and condition in join

Answer (score 2):

Put criteria in your left join:

```
Select distinct a.DeptID, b.DepartmentName, b.EmployeeID
From Department a
left join EmployeeDepartment b
on a.DeptID = b.DeptID and b.EmployeeID = 1 --insert employee ID here
```

It will show all departments (even those with no employees), then show the employee ID you chose in the third column only if that employee is assigned there.